# Loop through lines in file and increment variable to the next

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have the following content in a file:
These are just some timestamps

```
455860902
868790949
279116188
689905426
```

example - I would like following output

```
###########
sed -n '/455860902/,/868790949/p' file
sed -n '/868790949/,/279116188/p' file
sed -n '/279116188/,/689905426/p' file
```

It needs to go through a loop to save me from typing out the `sed`command each time.

Comment: So you want to output `sed` commands? The commands that you output seems to output the lines of the file in pairs. If you want to use the lines of `file` in pairs somewhere, there may be _much_ more efficient ways to do this. For example by reading the output of `paste <(sed '$d' file) <(sed '1d' file)` or just keeping track of the previous line and using that with the current line in a loop.

Comment: (contd.) ... in fact, you would have to do the exact type of processing to output the `sed` commands as the `sed` commands themselves are doing.

Comment: Would this do it `tail -n +2` (no need for the `sed`s)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using `awk`:

```
awk 'prev{ print "sed -n \047/" prev "/,/" $0 "/p\047 file"; }
         { prev=$0 }' infile
```

Comment: This works for me, but how to execute without printing and executing the commands. 
awk 'prev{  "sed -n \047/" prev "/,/" $0 "/p\047 file"; } { prev=$0 }' infile

Comment: `awk ..... | sh`. consider reading [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) next.

Comment: thx got it worked out all ok,

Answer (score 0):

Worked fine But its not as good as previous answer

```
la=`awk 'END{print NR}' filename`
co=$(($la - 1))

for i in `sed -n "1,"$co"p" filename`; do awk -v i="$i" '$1 ~ i {getline x;print "sed -n" " "  "/"$0"/,/"x"/p"}' filename; done| sed "s/\//'&/"| sed "s/\/p/\/p'/g"
```

output

```
sed -n '/455860902/,/868790949/p'
sed -n '/868790949/,/279116188/p'
sed -n '/279116188/,/689905426/p'
```